# Identify a succulent with flat whorled leaves

Tags: identification, succulents

So I bought this plant but don't know what it is. Any help would be much appreciated. (I don't know if its pot is the right size but that's what it came in so haven't changed it.)

I think it is an *Echeveria* of sorts (I know it's bent but I've moved it so it gets more sunlight so hopefully it will be OK)

[image: image 1]

Comment: Please ask a separate question for each plant; see https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/826/for-identification-please-only-post-one-plant-per-question-and-be-specific-whe for our policy. Thanks and welcome to the site.

Answer (score 4):

It's definitely Echeveria (sempervivums have a fine hairy fringe round the edge of the leaves and the leaves are thinner). It might be Echeveria 'Ramillette' https://mountaincrestgardens.com/echeveria-ramillette-ramillete/ but the redness round the edges is less visible on your plant, although under magnification, I can just see a hint of a red line on some of the lower leaves. The colouration  becomes more noticeable with good sun exposure; your plant looks as if it's not getting sufficient bright light, so it could be that variety, or one of the hundreds of others that exist.

Comment: I agree that it looks like it could use more sun.